# Can't access module in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have this module in `./src/utils/errorPopup.js`

```
import { Toast } from 'native-base';

export default function errorPopup(problem = 'process your request') {
  Toast.show({
    text: `Unfortunately we cannot ${problem}. An error report has been created and we will look into it shortly. Please get in touch with us if the problem doesn't disappear in the next 6 business hours.`,
    position: 'bottom',
    buttonText: 'Okay'
  });
}
```

I then try and call it inside the `componentWillMount` method of `./src/components/JobList.js` and it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: errorPopup is not defined`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import errorPopup from '../utils/errorPopup';

export default class JobsList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someObject: undefined
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://api.test.dev:5000/')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ someObject: response.data })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      errorPopup('fetch your accepted and available jobs');
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View />
    );
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, when I debug and use the console, I can see an object `_errorPopup2`.

How can I call `errorPopup()` without changing the design pattern of utils that I adopted from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html#utility-methods)?

Comment: It seems like the module path is not correct other wise try to print it console errorPopup and check what is in it.

Comment: @JayantPatil I double checked, the path seems correct

Comment: If you've ensured the path is right, try to simplify the setup by replacing the toast call by e.g. `console.warn('problem', problem);` in errorPopup.js and simply calling `errorPopup('...')` in `JobsList`'s `componentWillMount` without the async functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. I still get the same error.